# ¿Vagrant con php7 y MariaDB?

Tags: php, mariadb, vagrant

He estado buscando como puedo ejecutar vagrant con una máquina virtual que tenga php7 y MariaBD, pero no he encontrado como.
¿Alguien que tenga un ambiente así que me pueda ayudar?.
Nota:
Les adjunto un link en el cual me base para montar un ambiente con vagrant, pero usa MySQL y PHP 5 y quisiera cambiar las versiones.

https://geekytheory.com/tutorial-vagrant-1-que-es-y-como-usarlo/

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es simplemente tener una Vagrant con PHP7 y MariaDB, tienes muchas opciones de máquinas virtuales que ya incluyen esto, la más común actualmente es Homestead (de Laravel):

https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead

---

Si lo que deseas es aprender a crear tu propia máquina virtual con Vagrant y "aprovisionarla" (término Vagrant) con PHP7 y MariaDB de una forma más profesional que un simple script como el que está en el enlace que copiaste, puedes echarle un vistazo a [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) y [Berks](http://berkshelf.com/) (Ahora incluido en ChefDK) para que montes una receta que permita generar máquinas virtuales con todas las dependencias y paquetes necesarios.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, creo que optare por mi propia maquina.